# Cannot create a receiver function in Go on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: go, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Go in Jupyter Notebook as a way of documenting. I run the following compose:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  jupyter-go:
    image: gopherdata/gophernotes:latest-ds
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - "./src:/src"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

A link is generated where I can create and edit Notebooks on the browser.

However, every time I try to create a receiver function I got: "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference". A simple function like that below doesn't work:

```golang
import "fmt"

type person struct {
    firstName string
}

func (p person) print(){
    fmt.Println(p.firstName)
}

test := person {"Test"}
test.print() // runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

What is the root of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is:

splite your code two  part:

first part:

```
import "fmt"

type person struct {
    firstName string
}

func (p person) print(){
    fmt.Println(p.firstName)
}
```

seconde part

```
test := person {"Test"}
test.print() // runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

it will be run ok!

golang is not a scripting language like python. so it can't read struct once, also it is a bug to gophernotes

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative option, consider [GoNB](https://github.com/janpfeifer/gonb) (see [tutorial](https://github.com/janpfeifer/gonb/blob/main/examples/tutorial.ipynb)) as a Jupyter kernel for Go. It supports the more modern Go compiler, including generics, and is faster when executing (it compiles then executes) -- Disclaimer: I'm the author.

In GoNB it would look like:

```golang
import "fmt"

type person struct {
    firstName string
}

func (p person) print(){
    fmt.Println(p.firstName)
}

%%
test := person {"Test"}
test.print()
```

Or in two cells:

```golang
import "fmt"

type person struct {
    firstName string
}

func (p person) print(){
    fmt.Println(p.firstName)
}
```

And:

```golang
%%
test := person {"Test"}
test.print()
```

Note: everything in a cell after `%%` goes to a `func main() { ... }`.